# Why are Reports returning a 504 Gateway error?

Tags: reporting-services

I've created some reports in BIDS and uploaded the .rdl and .rds files to a SharePoint Report Library. Attempting to access the reports leads to a `504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.` message.

I've also attempted to replace the data source property on the report with a custom connection string and a stored credential with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

The 504 Gateway Timeout error is usually a network error between servers on the network or an issue with an actual server.

This may also mean that the report server is down or not working properly.

If you have manually configured the proxy , verify that Bypass proxy servers for local addresses is set to true.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding exception in your proxy server.

Or if you made any changes in your DNS then that will affect the performance

504 error is not something from SharePoint